# How to create a tint filter on my app?

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have been looking everywhere and I cant find an answer.

I want to know how to make a tint over the screen of my andriod app, so when I swipe up it goes like you are swiping a layer up.

So for example I open the app up and there is a transparent gray screen over the home screen of the app and I can swipe it up.

I know this is horribly explained so ask and i will try to be more descriptive. I am using visual studio and xamarin and c# for the andriod app. Many Thanks :). Any advice helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use absolute layout on your page. Add to it on top of all children semitransparent box with background color covering the whole screen. Implement gesture recogniser to detect fling up. When detected animate your box out of the screen. If you use forms then gesture recognizer will be in custom renderer of that box
For forms:

```
public class MyGestureListener : GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener
{
    OverlayBox box;

    public void SetBox(OverlayBox box)
    {
        this.box = box;
    }
    public override bool OnFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"OnFling velocityX={velocityX} velocityY={velocityY}");
        if (e2.RawY < e1.RawY) //add more constraints on X
        {
            Rectangle r = box.Bounds;
            r.Top = - r.Height;
            box.LayoutTo(r, 500);
        }
        //for fun
        Task.Delay(1000).ContinueWith(_ =>
        {
                Rectangle r1 = box.Bounds;
                r1.Top = 0;
                box.LayoutTo(r1, 500);
        }); 
        return base.OnFling(e1, e2, velocityX, velocityY);
    }
}


class OverlayBoxRenderer : ViewRenderer<OverlayBox, Android.Views.View>
{
    private readonly GestureDetector _detector;
    private readonly MyGestureListener _listener;
    public OverlayBoxRenderer()
    {
        _listener = new MyGestureListener();
        _detector = new GestureDetector(_listener);
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<OverlayBox> e)
    {
        if (e.NewElement == null)
        {
            this.Touch -= HandleTouch;
        }

        if (e.OldElement == null)
        {
            _listener.SetBox(e.NewElement);
            this.Touch += HandleTouch;
        }


    }

    void HandleTouch(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
    {
        _detector.OnTouchEvent(e.Event);
    }


}
```